# Can't get user location with swift using GoogleMaps

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am trying to get the user's location using the GoogleMaps API, but for some reason, when I run the simulator, the alert to get the user location won't come up and it won't show my current location either.

class UIMapsViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

}
```

The info.plist is targeted for my app, so that isn't the issue. I assume the issue is in the key in my info.plist file. I've tried both "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" and "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" but interestingly neither of those keys come up as suggestions in the list. Is there a different key to use now, or is that not my issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you've already run this code and you've already granted or denied authorization. Once that happens, you'll never see the authorization alert again for this app. You need to reset the simulator so that it forgets about your previous answer.

As for the other part of your question: I don't see what you expect as far as the user location is concerned. You are not *asking* for the user location so why would your app tell it to you? For example I don't see you setting the `myLocationEnabled` property of the Google map view. And I don't see you asking your CLLocationManager to tell you your location. So as far as your actual location is concerned, I don't see why you expect anything to happen.

Comment: That would make sense! I wouldn't want it to ask users over and over again, but it never asked me for my location and the simulator certainly isn't using the location because it pops up somewhere in Europe.

Comment: You seem a little confused here. It's never going to ask you "for your location". The purpose of Location Services is that you don't _know_ your location, and the _device_ will tell it to you. It's going to ask you for _permission_ (authorization) to _detect_ your location.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I understand what it's asking, but the issue is two fold. First, it doesn't ask at all. Second, since it never asks for permission, it doesn't show me my location.

Comment: I was responding to the part of your question about the alert. I don't see you _doing_ anything that would _cause_ the app to show you your location, so that part of your question makes no sense to me.

Comment: if I understand the directions correctly, the "alert" is established in the .plist file with the key "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription." I don't create an alert myself inside my viewController

Comment: I would suggest testing on a device, not the Simulator.